# Nexus path for Nexus2Art tool

Tags: nexus, artifactory

I am trying to migrate Nexus to JFrog Artifactory and so I am using Nexus2Art tool where I need to pass the `Nexus Path`. When I  tried to get the help for `Nexus Path`, it gave output as

> The local file path to the Nexus instance. For efficiency reasons, this tool requires file system access to the Nexus server, and so must be run on the same server, or on a computer with access to the file system where Nexus is installed, and must be run by a user with read access to the Nexus installation's directory tree. The correct path to put in this field is a directory containing the folders: 'conf', 'indexer', 'logs', 'storage', 'timeline', and others.

So, I gave my Nexus Installation directory i.e., `C:\Program Files (x86)\nexus-2.14.4-03` as the `Nexus Path`. But it was throwing an error as

> ERROR:nex2art.core.Nexus:Nexus config file does not exist.
>
> Given path is not a valid Nexus instance.

I opened the command prompt in `admin` mode.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues at the start when we introduced this tool in our environment. Your nexus path should look like /proj/../../sonatype-work/nexus. You should run on the same instance by the way. It has many limitations to use this tool as far observed. It will have latency when migrating large repos. Firewall issues are quite common during the migration on both sides of artifactory and nexus. Also make sure to have latest python module running .